# Why doesn't this thread terminate?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I can not get this thread to terminate.  Where did I make an error?

```
type
  TThumbnailThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure CreateContactSheets;
  end;

procedure TThumbnailThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
     CreateContactSheets;
     Synchronize(CreateContactSheets);
  end;
end;

procedure TThumbnailThread.CreateContactSheets;
const
  iColumns: integer = 6;
  iRows: integer = 6;
  iHorzontalSpace: integer = 0;
  iVerticalSpace: integer = 0;
  iHorzontalMargin: integer = 0;
  iVerticalMargin: integer = 0;
  iDrawBox: boolean = true;
  iDrawText: boolean = True;
  iDrawShadow: boolean = True;
  iBackgroundColor: TColor = clWhite;
  iBoxColor: TColor = clBlack;
  iPageNo: Integer = -1;
begin
  Form1.ImageEnMView1.MIO.PrintImagesToFile(Form1.AThumbnailFilename, 80, Screen.Width,
      Screen.Height, iColumns, Rows, iHorzontalSpace, iVerticalSpace,
      Form1.PrintSelected1.Checked, iHorzontalMargin, iVerticalMargin, iDrawBox, iDrawText,
      iDrawShadow, iBackgroundColor, iBoxColor, iPageNo);
end;

procedure TForm1.PrintToFile1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SavePictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    if SavePictureDialog1.FileName <> '' then
    begin
      Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
      try
        iFilename := SavePictureDialog1.FileName;
        { If one thread have been started already, we don't start another. }
        if ThumbnailThread <> nil then
          raise Exception.Create('One thread has already been started!');
        AThumbnailFilename := iFilename;
        ThumbnailThread := TThumbnailThread.Create(false);
        ThumbnailThread.OnTerminate := TerminateTheThread;
      finally
        Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Abort1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ThumbnailThread.Terminate;
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;

procedure TForm1.TerminateTheThread;
begin
  Form1.ImageEnMView1.MIO.Aborting := True;
end;
```

Comment: Note that CreateContactSheets() deals with VCL. The first call to CreateContactSheets() in Execute() is not wrapped in Synchronize i.e. it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no reason to have a thread here. You're doing all of the work in a synchronized method, which halts the main thread while it's running. You're creating a thread that does nothing but pause itself to run something back in the main thread.

Your thread isn't terminating because `Form1.ImageEnMView1.MIO.PrintImagesToFile` has no way of checking to see if the `Thread.Terminate` variable has been set, so as long as `PrintImagesToFile` runs the flag isn't checked. Since the thread has been paused because you're running a synchronized method (which runs in the context of the main thread), the thread never knows it has been terminated until after all of the work has been done.

Comment: So you are advising me that there is no way to call Form1.ImageEnMView1.MIO.PrintImagesToFile in a thread so the procedure can be aborted?

Comment: @Bill You should rethink your concept using threads. It is a very bad idea just to call a form method from inside the thread to do all the work and doing this synchronized will "unthread" your thread.

Comment: @Bill Hand over **all** necessary information to the thread to get the background work done. `Synchronize` or `Queue` only status information (e.g. Progress) and check the `Terminated` flag during the work.

Comment: @Bill: I'm telling you your current implementation is a waste of time, because you're doing nothing in the thread. All of the work is being done in the main (GUI) thread. As far as whether you can tell `ImageEnMView1.MIO` to abort, I have no idea, because I have no idea what that control does or the functionality it exposes, so I can't comment on it. I can only answer regarding the question you've asked here, which is why **this thread isn't terminating**, and I've answered that question. If you have a different question about your component, post it as a new question.

Comment: @Ken,  Ok.  Thanks for your help.  I will stop my attempt to thread this.  ImageEnMView1.MIO can be set to abort but all that does is abort creating the current page and continues on with the remaining pages.  I'll continue my discussion with the developer.

Comment: @Bill Sir Rufo told you how to do it.  When using threads prepare a job for them to do that's totally self-contained.  The only communication should be abort/I'm done/here's my progress.